# What would cause a terminal to explode like that on a circuit breaker switch?

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker, water-heater

My landlord was having his fun turning on and off my stove and hot water to get me to move out instead of fixing broken windows.
As soon as the police got involved and my lawyer sent a notice, he had to make it look like something was actually wrong.

When my stove and hot water went off, I was sleeping. Nothing was on. Not the stove. I wasn't running water. I didnt even have the tv on. I was awoken my landlord at the door in the morning and when he left thats when I learned the stove was off and the water got cold the following day.

He sent me these pictures. Is there anything tell tale?
Also note that he only changed the water heater switch but the oven was off too.
Look at the discoloration of the old switch on the wall and the one on the counter.  The one on the counter is black and not discolored. I dont even think that switch belonged to this house[image]

[image]

Comment: what's your question? ... circuit breakers are the responsibility of the landlord ... the one in the bottom picture is burned, probably from a poor connection in the breaker panel ... it may not even be compatible with the panel ... can you get a picture of the whole panel? ... with cover removed,  if possible

Comment: Can you post photos of the labeling on the inside of the door to the panel in question?

Comment: Include a picture of the face of the broken breaker with all the labeling. Also, while it doesn't address the issue you're after and is off-topic for this stack, it seems to me that moving out would be in your best interest. If the landlord is going to make your life miserable, there's not much sense in sticking around. Sure, you can fight him, but that means every day is going to be a battle and the legal fees will be significantly more than rent at a nicer place with a nicer landlord...

Comment: The landlord doing electrical work? In all of the states I have worked as a professional electrician this would be a violation.  How would the landlord know there was a problem? A bad connection , bad breaker either could be the cause but that looks like a bolt to buss breaker and the damage is not normal.  In all the states I have worked an electrical license is required to work on stuff like this but a failed breaker could be a reason for a intermittent issue like you report.